# Not able to reproduce checkmarx scann results using SFDX scanner

Tags: security-review, security-scanner

We got these below eeors when we submitter our code for security review in salesforce portal

[image]

In order to fix the issue we are trying to replicate the issues using SFDX scanner in our local but SFDX is giving the results as we got from security portal.

We fixed the issues but is there a way we can check whether those issues are fixed before submitting to security portal?

Comment: Are you using the partner security portal? If so, you have up to three scans you can run for your submission so why not use one of those (and if all is fine you can submit these results with your re-submission)?

Comment: @PhilW. Yes we are using partner security portal. Actually what we thought is before re submissions we are trying to make sure that its error free in our local dev.

Comment: That is what the three free scans are for. Obviously you can help by running the SFDX scanner too, but as you have realised these actually find different issues.

Comment: FYI, Salesforce has negotiated an updated contract that allows for one scan per package version now, which should provide you with more flexibility to double check results. This functionality requires a partner login to the partner security portal, and of course the package should be for the appexchange security review.